# Update .WAR file without causing Tomcat to pause serving web pages in production server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Hi,

When I re-upload my ROOT.war file to my Java Tomcat 8 web server by replacing the existing /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/webapps/ROOT.war file with the new one, Tomcat stops serving web pages for about 15 seconds while the WAR file is being over-written by my ftp program. This is irritating as I'd like to be able to change the jsp pages on the fly and allow people to continue using the web site.

This happens using the default configuration of the global web.xml file, and when I changed the jsp servlet parameters to this:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>fork</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value><!-- Changed from false to true -->
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
        <!-- New additions -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>development</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>checkInterval</param-name>
            <param-value>10</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!-- End of new additions -->
    </servlet>
```

Any tips would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you expect--unpacking and restarting a web app takes time. If it's unacceptable you could spin up another Tomcat and do an instantaneous switchover once the new one is up or something. But with a war there's an intrinsic overhead as opposed to deploying an exploded war where you can just copy a JSP over. Even then, correct behavior depends on actual implementation details.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try uploading the exploded war file rather than the file itself. It's strange that Tomcat can't explode the file, compare the old file's and new file's contents, and update as necessary without pausing itself. Seems like a pretty handy and obvious feature. I wonder how news sites that use JavaEE do it? They obviously update their content all the time without pausing their web server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cluster for your application by stooping and upgrading server one by one  will help